# Squid config to ensure HTTP header matches that of the cached content

Tags: apache, https, http-headers, squid, cache-control

We have a cloud setup like this:

```
User Request -> Perlbal (SSL unwrapping) -> Squid (Caching) -> Apache -> HTTP Response
```

We support SSL on some pages, and not on others.  Everything beyond the perlbal layer only process requests over unencrypted HTTP since perlbal unwraps the SSL, but it does add an `X-Forwarded-Proto` header so that the application knows if SSL was used or not.

If a request hits the application (Apache) over HTTP, when that particular page requires SSL it redirects to HTTPS.

When a request for a secure resource reaches our application, and if the application sends `Cache-Control: public`, squid caches that content correctly.  The problem is that if the user then tries to access the HTTP version of that resource once it's cached, squid processes it as a cache HIT and returns the cached resource over HTTP, when in fact we need it to consider it a cache MISS because X-Forwarded-Proto does not match the original request.

How is this done?  Our application sends:

```
Vary: X-Forwarded-Proto,Accept-Encoding
```

I'm having a hard time finding any articles/documentation on this and this Vary header seems to be what other people suggest, but it is not working.  Squid serves the cached content regardless of the X-Forwarded-Proto header indicating SSL or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMFG.

We had this in our .htaccess for historical reasons:

```
BrowserMatch "MSIE" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/4.[0-9]{2}" brokenvary=1
BrowserMatch "Opera" !brokenvary
SetEnvIf brokenvary 1 force-no-vary
```

Three guesses what happens to the squid cache once an IE 6 user visits our site.  Vary header removed.  Caching strategy broken.

Screw IE.  Removing this was a good move.  Everything working now.